# Search Engine Optimize a photography website?

Tags: seo, php, web-development, photo-gallery

Because most photography websites are mostly photo galleries, I'm at a loss on how to code my new site.

You can choose a friendly url, use alt tags for every image, include language set, meta tags, add a sitemap, doctype, maybe throw a H1, favicon, and robots.txt. There are a few things you can use microdata for, but not many.

The **low amount of text makes it unique in SEO** (navbar and footer texts, more or less) which means **the standard guidelines of current optimization do not apply** because it leaves hardly anything for search engines to grab, though it may rank higher by having less trashy code in the page itself and maybe alt text counts as much as paragraph text for keywords, though I doubt it.

All that said, what's the best way for me to design and optimize a photography website other than the techniques I listed in the second paragraph?

Image sliders? Gallery of thumbnails? What are the SEO pros and cons of each method? Page loading time may be a factor of rank, but what of large or small numbers of alt text versus faster loading time? Which is better ranking?

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I am asking how to specifically structure in code, and optimize, a photo gallery website, because it is different than any other kind of website. Please do not skip to the last line of my post and mark it duplicate.

Comment: It isn't different to any other website. The fundamentals of optimising a website remains the same regardless of content/type (hence [the question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google) linked to).

Comment: @zigojacko Indeed, fundamentals, which I already listed. I'm asking for specifics related to the uniquity found in this kind of website, because it's different. The linked thread mentions nothing at all of whether sliders or thumbnail galleries are more effective, nor how do deal with websites with very little text content on them (in fact everything in that thread boasts about more text and blog systems, which you can't do here) or which specific microdata tags would be advantageous to use in this situation. Those things are why I made this specific question; they are not answered elsewhere.